# WAL files in HBase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

In HBase before writing into memstore data will be first written into the WAL, but when i checked on my system
WAL files are not getting updated immediately after each **Put** operation, it's taking lot of time to update. Is there any parameter i need to set?
(**WAL has been enabled**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In standalone mode writing into WAL is taking a lot of time, where as on pseudo distributed mode it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how long it takes to update the WAL files? Are you sure the time is taken in write or by the time you check WAL, it is already moved to old logs. If WAL is enabled all the entries must come to WAL first and then written to particular region as cluster configured.

I know that WAL files are moved to .oldlogs fairly quickly i.e. 60 seconds as defined in hbase-site.xml through hbase.master.logcleaner.ttl setting.

Comment: Thanx for the reply...I am running HBase in standalone mode, sure the time is taken in writing into WAL. Is there any parameter which controls writing into WAL interms of time or size